# C++ Debug Problem - pdb file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pdb-files

I have several DLLs in my project that are defined to create their *.pdb file (debug info) inside the same folder. The problem is that the only *.pdb file that actually exist inside this folder is the one that belongs to the last compiled DLL. As a result I can debug only the last project (each compilation deletes all the *.pdb in the folder and creates the current compiled DLL pdb file.)

How can I resolve it ? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: What is your project structure (are they all in the same solution)? What is you build process and (really obvious) but are your `.pdb` all called something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can create separate folder for program releases, and always compile and execute your program from the newest release-folder. This way you can also manage all other external files like images and what not.

Comment: This isn't a solution. It leads to exactly the same problem if you only do that.

Comment: Well, of course all programs should have own release-folders and stored separately.

Comment: I guess i misread then what you meant. "*Compile [...] from the newest release-folder*" i a bit misleading.

Answer (score 5):

You either remove `*.pdb` from *Extensions to delete on clean* in the project settings or, better, use different *Intermediate Directories*.
Both settings are in *Configuration Properties* -> *General*.

Comment: +1 for diffferent intermediate directories. A good practice to avoid clashes of obj-files too (node.obj anyone? :)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't even aware that it was possible to share intermediate directories without eveything going horribly wrong.